Reading material for Bellman's optimality principle in dynamic programming - for someone who is not familiar with control theory
I am trying to understand the underlying theory behind dynamic programming, given the fact that I am not familiar with control theory, I fail to find relevant reading material that addresses the this topic (see question title).
I checked similar questions, although very helpful, I would like something that addresses Bellman's optimality principle and its relation to dynamic programming.
I apologize if I missed a previous question that addresses this topic.

Hi: This looks pretty compact but good at the same time. Note that one can learn and understand Bellman's optimality principle and dynamic programming without touching control theory at all.  https://people.hec.edu/rosu/wp-content/uploads/sites/43/2020/03/bellman.pdf

Thank you for you answer, I will check this now.

Update (to anyone looking for something similar):
I found this book which has a chapter about Dynamic Programming: Optimal Control Theory: An Introduction by D. E. Kirk.
I will update this thread If I find something interesting.
